# Translation model in App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker, language-translation

I would to make the field descriptions and label texts in my pages multi-lingual. Originally they are in English and I could let the user translate them through Google Translate. In order to avoid translation errors I would like to implement a translation data model that contains

- FieldDisplayName / LabelText
- FieldDisplayName_DE
- FieldDisplayName_FR
- FieldDisplayName_IT
- etc.

All the pages contain a page header fragment that contains a menu button, searchbox etc. like in the **Starter App** template. I am planning on integrating a dropdown widget in the page header that allows to choose between the languages (DE,EN,FR,IT,...). Is it possible to bind the display name to the user's selection? How would I have to implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way (to implement/use/maintain) that would provide highest possible translation quality will be introducing Translation data model with the following structure:

```
+----+--------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
| Id | Locale | FirstName  | LastName   | Age        | ... |
+----+--------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
| 1  | EN     | First name | Last name  | Age        | ... |
+----+--------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
| 2  | RU     | Имя        | Фамилия    | Возраст    | ... |
+----+--------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
| 3  | DE     | Voornaam   | Achternaam | Leeftijd   | ... |
+----+--------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
| 4  | ...    | ...        | ....       | ...        | ... |
+----+--------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
```

In this model every column represents unique label within your app and every row represents labels's translations for supported languages. This model can be easily used in label bindings:

```javascript
@datasources.UserTranslations.item.FieldNameToTranslate
```

Maintaining these translation will be easy as well, just drag and drop editable table on UI.

Here is a [query script](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#query_script) for the UserTranslations datasource:

```javascript
// Assuming that you already have robust user settings implementation.
var userSettings = getUserSettings_();

var query = app.models.Translation.newQuery();
query.filters.Locale._equals = userSettings.Locale;

return query.run();
```

Radically **different implementation** will be

1. Introducing [Calculated Model](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/calculated) with the same set of fields as in the previous approach
2. Using [Model Metadata API](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/server#ModelMetadata) to extract display names from the model's fields
3. Translate fields using [Translate API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/language/)
4. Populate calculated model record with translated values

Here is super high level server ***pseudo script*** for that flow:

```javascript
var userLocale = getUserLocaleFromUserSettings();
var fieldsDisplayNames = getFieldsDisplayNames(app.models.Translation);
var translations = translate(fieldsDisplayNames, 'en', userLocale);

var record = app.models.Translation.newRecord();

mapRecordFieldsToTranslations(record, translations);

return [record];
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trials a translation model turned out to be too laggy for my demands. Therefore I have hardcoded the binding expression into the labels I want to translate. The binding expression looks a little bit like this:

```
(@pages.UserSettings.LanguageDropdown.value == 'EN') ? 'Contact' : 'Kontakt'
```